# User authentication over Dante proxy server

Tags: authentication, proxy, socks

Below is my Dante SOCKS Proxy server configuration that I connect to without any authentication:

```
internal: eth0 port = 53200
internal: 127.0.0.1 port = 53200
external: eth0

clientmethod: none
method: none
user.privileged: root

client pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error # connect disconnect
}
pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
protocol: tcp udp
log: error # connect disconnect
}
```

I have set up a user group in linux with many members. I want members of this group to be able to connect to the proxy server using authentication (via proxifier).

How can I enforce user authentication with Dante ?

Answer (score 1):

Below configuration will enforce authentication:

```
internal: eth0 port = 53200
internal: 127.0.0.1 port = 53200
external: eth0

method: username
user.privileged: root

client pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error # connect disconnect
}
pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
protocol: tcp udp
log: error # connect disconnect
}
```

Comment: It slows down when I use authentication. what should I do?